# Create instance of slice using reflection at run time

Tags: go, reflection

I was trying to pass the slice of structs i.e. `[]carDetail` or `[]bikeDetail` which implement the `IMapping` interface in the   `func fetch(url string, itemList []IMapping) (error)`. But then came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994679/golang-slice-of-struct-slice-of-interface-it-implements). GoLang doesn't support it. So, changed the signature to be `func fetch(url string, itemList IMapping) (error)`. Now, I am trying to pass the `carDetail` or `bikeDetail` struct in the function and in the `fetch` function trying to create the slice of struct using reflection. So, how can I do that? Which further can be passed in the `json.Unmarshal` method to map the json to struct.

```
type IMapping interface {
        GetId() int
    }

    type carDetail struct {
        ModelId    int    `json:"modelId"`
        CarName  string `json:"carName"`
    }
    func (m *carDetail) GetId() int {
        return m.ModelID
    }

    type bikeDetail struct {
        ModelId    int    `json:"modelId"`
        BikeName  string `json:"bikeName"`
    }

    func (m *bikeDetail) GetId() int {
        return m.ModelID
    }

    func fetch(url string, itemList IMapping) (error) {

        var myClient = &http.Client{}
        r, err := myClient.Get(url)
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        defer r.Body.Close()

        // how to create slice at run time using reflection say objVehicle

        err = json.Unmarshal(body, &objVehicle)

        .....
    }
```

Comment: you can use struct directly without interface and create a slice of struct in your fetch function to unmarshal the data

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440646/how-to-create-a-generic-function-to-unmarshal-all-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `fetch` to take an interface{} argument:

```
func fetch(url string, itemList interface{}) (error) {
    var myClient = &http.Client{}
    r, err := myClient.Get(url)
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    defer r.Body.Close()
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, itemList)
    .....
}
```

Call it with a pointer to a slice of the appropriate type:

```
var details []carDetail
err := fetch(u, &details)
```

With this approach, the json.Umarshal function does all the heavy lifting.